# window function for Spark 1.6

Tags: apache-spark, window, udf

I have this DataFrame :

```
+----+------+--------------------+--------+-------------+ 
| id | name |    end time        |  value |    comment  |
---------------------------------------------------------
|1   |node1 |2017-03-24 08:30:00 |    5   | blabla      |
---------------------------------------------------------
|2   |node1 |2017-03-24 09:00:00 |    3   | blabla      |
---------------------------------------------------------
|3   |node1 |2017-03-24 09:30:00 |    8   | blabla      |
---------------------------------------------------------
|4   |node2 |2017-03-24 10:00:00 |    5   | blabla      |
---------------------------------------------------------
|5   |node2 |2017-03-24 10:30:00 |    3  | blabla      |
---------------------------------------------------------
|6   |node2 |2017-03-24 11:00:00 |    1   | blabla      |
---------------------------------------------------------
|7   |node2 |2017-03-24 11:30:00 |    3   | blabla      |
---------------------------------------------------------
|8   |node2 |2017-03-24 12:00:00 |    5  | blabla      |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

And I need to find nodes with value less than 6 during 2 hours. How I can do it in Spark 1.6?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT : This is only in Spark 2.x**

You can use window aggregate functions :

```
df.groupBy(
    col("name"),
    window(col("end time"), "2 hour", "30 minute")
)
.agg(max("value").as("2_hour_max_value"))
.filter(col("2_hour_max_value") < 6)
.select("name")
.distinct()
```

Comment: how to import window function?

Comment: `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._`

Comment: window function added in spark 2.0, I use 1.6

Comment: how  can I do it in 1.6 version?

Comment: Oh yes sorry. Window time functions are available only for Spark 2. To do it in Spark 1.6 won't be easy.

Comment: any ideas? how I can do it Spark1.6 ?

Comment: really no idea how to do it in Spark 1.6 ... I will edit my post and you can unapprove my answer.

Answer (score 0):

in Spark 1.6 Windowing function are only available with HiveContext. So you have to create hiveContext.

```
val hiveContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
```

In order to utilize hiveContext, you have to register dataframe as temp table and run query with windowing function on temp table using hiveContext.

```
df.registerTempTable("dfTable")


val df = hiveContext.sql("""SELECT *,
                                row_number() over(partition by <partitionColum> order by <orderColumn> ) AS rank
                         FROM dfTable""")
```

Comment: When I tried this approach, i get an exception dfTable not found.  Also not sure why your table name is dfTabledfTable?

Comment: Corrected typo (dfTabledfTable --> dfTable)

Answer (score 0):

For folks that are still using **Spark 1.6**:

Need to create dataframe using hivecontext. Otherwise, hiveContext.sql will not recognize the registered table.  Here is an example in spark shell:

```
val hiveContext=new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
val someRDD=....
var someDF=hiveContext.createDataFrame(someRDD)
someDF=someDF.withColumnRenamed("_1","col1")....
someDF.registerTempTable("someTbl")
val ranked=hiveContext.sql("SELECT *, row_number() OVER(PARTITION by col1,col2,col3 order by col4 desc) AS rank FROM someTbl")
val maxCountPerGroup=ranked.filter(ranked("rank")===1).drop("rank")
maxCountPerGroup.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save(output)
```